# New environment as a single box

Tags: macros, spacing, environments, boxes

I am making my new environment for headings. It is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\headspace}
\setlength{\headspace}{3mm plus 2mm minus 2mm}
\newlength{\rulespace}
\setlength{\rulespace}{5mm plus 2mm minus 3mm}

\newcounter{headcounter}
\setcounter{headcounter}{0}

\newenvironment{heading}{%
\vspace{\rulespace}%
\hrule height 0.7pt%
\vspace{\headspace}%
\refstepcounter{headcounter}%
\centering\Large\bfseries\scshape\Roman{headcounter}.}
{\vspace{\headspace}%
\hrule%
\vspace{\rulespace}}

\begin{heading}
Introduction
\end{heading}
\end{document}
```

It works but this heading does not behave like a united single box. I mean it can be broken through pages. If to implement this without environments, I would put the two horizontal rules and the heading itself in `\vbox` to make it inseparable. If I use `\vbox{}` in my `heading` environment, there is an error. I place `\vbox{` in the beginning part of my environment and the corresponding `}` goes to the ending part. What should I do to make the heading environment a single box that won't be broken through pages?

Comment: Please don't post fragments of code. Put them into comilable documents that people can work with.

Comment: you could start and end a minipage in your environment, but why not use a more nomal latex heading declaration that would take care of other things like not allowing a page break until after the first line of the next paragraph

Comment: @AlanMunn, I've edited my original post

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am studying LaTeX and I have an exercise to make a new environment. It is just for studying. I'll read about minipage, thank you for the advice!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've added ```\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}``` to the beginning of my environment and ```\end{minipage}``` in ending. It works, thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered to the OP's satisfaction in comments and is unlikely (I think?) to be of wider interest.

Comment: @cfr, it is a moderator or me who should close the question? I do not see where I could do this.

Comment: @Vladimir You don't have to do anything. It will show up in a review queue and/or people can vote to close here. No need to bother the mods. I don't think you can close it yourself.

Comment: @Vladimir Oh, and ignore the 'off-topic' bit. The choice of reasons for closing is rather limited.